# If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)}$ exist so they exist in some neighborhood?

Tags: calculus

I was reading Spivak proof for L'hospital rule and he says this that:
If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)}$ exist so there is an interval
$(a-\delta ; a+ \delta$) such that $F'(x)$ and $G'(x)$ exist

I didn't understand why, if this proof its gonna use Cauchy Mean Value Theorem

Comment: False as written. The point $a$ must be excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Spivak says that the existence of $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)}$ *implicitly* means that $F'(x)$ and $G'(x)$ exists in an interval $(a - \delta,a + \delta)$ **except maybe** at $x = a$.

Comment: But, Why is this true?

Comment: @Jordan, because $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ only makes sense when $f$ is defined in a deleted neighborhood (http://www.mathwords.com/d/deleted_nbhd.htm) of the point.

Comment: True, i have forgotten. But if we take G'= $\frac 1F'$ ? If F doesn't have the limit, so does this affirmation make no sense, and the quociente has the limit

Comment: @Jordan, you *can't* take $G' = 1/F'$ because $F$, $G$ are given functions.

Comment: Understood now, the same i may say if that a function is continous in a point ? That exist some interval around this point which the function certainly is continous though?

Comment: @Jordan, that the function is *defined* in a neighborhood of the point.

Comment: I guess its 100% now, because if i know it has a derivative over an interval so its continuous, and from this i may apply, Mean Value theorem. Thank you so much

Comment: @Jordan, if the answer has been useful, you can accept it.

Comment: Regarding different opinions/definitions of when a limit may make sense: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170178/limit-of-frac-sin-frac-1-x-sin-frac-1-x-as-x-goes-to-zero/3170290#3170290